# Unable to import library with maven

Tags: java, android, maven, shared-libraries

I am trying to import Ripple Effect library by using maven https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect.

It says "The lib is available on Maven Central, you can find it with Gradle, please". I have no idea what Gradle, please is and it's information (http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#rippleeffect) didn't help me at all.

I found how to import it by using maven. I added this dependency to my POM:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.traex.rippleeffect</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

and made sure that I have Maven central repository:

```
<repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

However, when I try to run the project, it says:

```
Failed to execute goal on project ProjectName: Could not resolve dependencies for project lt.adnera:ProjectName:apk:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:jar:1.3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding this: compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3' in your dependencies of Gradle ?

Comment: @Spirrow It is maven project, not gradle.

Comment: I found it here http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#rippleeffect and if I am not misunderstanding it says gradle

Comment: @Spirrow clearly you have no idea what you are talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/traex/rippleeffect/library/1.3/library-1.3.pom the packaging is aar so there is no jar which can be downloaded.
Try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.traex.rippleeffect</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

additional Infos: http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/aar.html